# Which Wordpress file controls the featured image upload maximum width and height of 3000px

Tags: uploads

Ok so i read a forum somewhere... that gave instructions on how to hardcode change the maximum image upload global values for "featured image" for woo commerce products, from a max of 3000px width and height so that I could restrict vendors from uploading large images. So I changed the values to 500px wide X 600px high, and it works like magic!!! BUT now I need to change it back and I've forgotten which file I changed due to a computer dying on me..... AAAAARG 
does anyone know where these settings live in the wordpress structure so I can reverse it back to 3000px X 3000px?

Comment: WordPress doesn't set maximum dimensions for uploaded images. You must've edited a plugin or added your own code. No one here can tell you which file you edited when it could be almost anything.

Comment: I think it was a .css file but it was definitely in the wordpress structure... max width=3000px AND max height=3000px ... Apparently wordpress defines these values for the featured image as a standard... I changed them to 500px x 600px and it restricts my vendors from uploading anything larger.

Comment: WordPress does not do that. If it was done with CSS then it would've been your theme. And CSS only affects the display of the image. It wouldn't prevent users uploading a larger image.

Comment: Ok so that narrows it down because I just tried uploading a large product featured image as admin and it allowed it BUT when logged in as a vendor it prevented it sooo if i didn't do it in wordpress that makes me happier as it narrows down the search... but now I'm not sure it was a css it might have been a .js file... as these are the two file types I'm not very familiar with.... doah! wish i'd never changed it.... could be a year down the drain...

Comment: Dump your database and search (grep) for lines with "500", "600" and "max" in them.

Comment: Grep??? how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's set at the PHP level. In `php.ini` there's a line like

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

which you may need to add or change. The file is at the root of your site, and might have to be added if it isn't there already.
It's also possible to limit the size via the `.htaccess` file (which the web server looks at, and again is at the root of your site).

Also, this is a blanket limit, so if you wanted the limits to vary by role you'd probably need a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for that but that's not the issue... i've change the core max_image_upload width= 3000px into width=500px

Comment: I either did this in Wordpress, WC vendors Pro, Woocommerce, PaidMemberships Pro... or some theme file.... I seem to remember it being a .css or a .js  file that I changed because it was a min file.